# Absolute isotope activity in a nuclear fallout

Tags: nuclear-physics, isotopes

I've seen nice graph showing *relative* activity of each isotope in Chernobyl fallout:
[image]

Could anyone suggest similar graph or raw data but for *absolute* isotope activity for the case of nuclear explosion fallout? (for some boosted fission bomb)

So that one could see how much gamma, beta and alpha-active particles one should expect over time, and particle  energy.

PS. This graph is for damaged nuclear plant fallout, but I want absolute graph for nuclear explosion fallout. Explosions have different isotope content due to much shorter duration.

**Update:** I see that graph might be hard to find. Maybe someone have isotope content i.e. how much % of each isotope? Or at least how it is supposed to be different from Chernobyl fallout. Then I might be able to simulate decay by myself.

Comment: What is the source of the graph?

Comment: @BenCrowell Wiki "Nuclear fission product" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AirDoseChernobylVector.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can you  not use this plot?  It is given relative to the radiation level.Assume a [radiation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster#Radiation_levels)  and multiply by the percentage, and you will get the absolutes for shortly after the explosion as the table is labeled.

Your question then becomes : *What is the radiation level versus time.*

[This paper](http://polymer.bu.edu/~sergey/pub/PRE/PRE04389.pdf) has activity concentrations for Chernobyl versus time and there are fluctuations about the expected exponential decay , it is not a simple story. If you are ambitious you can use the information in the paper to transform your plot from percentages to absolute numbers for a given time; places also play a role.

Comment: Because it's a plot for damaged nuclear plant fallout, and I want it for nuclear explosion fallout - it has different isotope proportions. I probably need to specify it clearer.

Comment: This has some data in plots  http://www3.nd.edu/~nsl/Lectures/phys205/pdf/Nuclear_Warfare_9.pdf . The wikipedia has a comparison of Chernobyl and bombs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Chernobyl_and_other_radioactivity_releases#Chernobyl_compared_with_an_atomic_bomb . I suppose most data from bomb tests are still classified.